# Modifying a data using factoring levels

Tags: r, r-factor

dat$Gender is data that contains a vector of m's, M's, f's, and F's. I am trying to modify the variable 'Gender` so that the uppercase letters changed to lowercase by using factors.

```
  [1] m m m f m M f m m f m f f m m m f m m F f m f f m M M f m f f m m m m f f m M m f m m m f f M
 [48] M m m m f f f m f m m m f f f f M f m f f M m m m F m m f M M M f m M M m m f f f m m f m F f
 [95] m m F m M M
Levels: f F m M
```

```
dat$Gender
```

The code outputs N/A for some of the values. What am I doing wrong?

```
data_Gender<- factor(dat$Gender, levels=c("m","M","f","F"),labels= c("m","m","f","f"))
data_Gender
```

```
  [1] m    m    m    f    m    <NA> f    m    m    f    m    f    f    m    m    m    f    m    m   
 [20] <NA> f    m    f    f    m    <NA> <NA> f    m    f    f    m    m    m    m    f    f    m   
 [39] <NA> m    f    m    m    m    f    f    <NA> <NA> m    m    m    f    f    f    m    f    m   
 [58] m    m    f    f    f    f    <NA> f    m    f    f    <NA> m    m    m    <NA> m    m    f   
 [77] <NA> <NA> <NA> f    m    <NA> <NA> m    m    f    f    f    m    m    f    m    <NA> f    m   
 [96] m    <NA> m    <NA> <NA>
Levels: m < f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the levels directly like this: `levels(x) <- tolower(levels(x))`. The `levels` need to be a character vector, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of re-levelling can be achieved with `forcats::fct_collapse`. However, as already suggested there are other better/simpler ways to do that.

```
dat <- data.frame(Gender = c('M', 'F', 'M', 'f', 'm'))
dat$Gender <- forcats::fct_collapse(dat$Gender, 'M' = c('M', 'm'), 
                                                'F' = c('F', 'f'))

dat
#  Gender
#1      M
#2      F
#3      M
#4      F
#5      M
```